# Download Files and store them in asset folder with PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I'd like to know that if its possible to download file into asset folder of phonegap project in android

Comment: what you want to do ?? download it in an assets only ??

Comment: yes but since its read only so it cant be I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assets are read-only and cannot be written to at runtime.

Comment: my aim is to download a file and access it after downloading. so how can I achieve it.Please Help..

Comment: I'm not versed in phonegap but generally you would download to somewhere under your application's data dir and access it there.

Comment: one more doubt i want to clear it out i.e can we write into asset folder using native code after making it as a plugin.Is this possible

Comment: No, the assets are packaged in the application binary package which can only be modified at compile time.

Comment: You can download it to any other folder in sdcard or by creating a new folder you can download in it..!!